# Change font size in php csv output

Tags: php, csv, prestashop

I have no idea how to change the font size for a specific code, since it has no echo etc. This is a module in Prestashop 1.5 and its php.
All text in the code below should be font size 18, currently its 10..

```
    $addressdata .= ''.chr(13).chr(13);
        $addressdata .= utf8_encode((strlen(str_replace('-','',$address->company))>0 ? $address->company.chr(13) : ''));
        $addressdata .= utf8_encode($address->firstname.' '.$address->lastname.chr(13));
        $addressdata .= utf8_encode($address->address1.chr(13));
        $addressdata .= utf8_encode((strlen(str_replace('-','',$address->address2))>0 ? $address->address2.chr(13) : ''));
        $addressdata .= utf8_encode($address->postcode.' '.$address->city.chr(13));
        $addressdata .= $this->getCountryName($address->id_country, $order->id_lang).chr(13).chr(13);
        $addressdata .= ''.chr(13).chr(13);
```

Comment: CSV doesn't have a "font size" any more than HTML, CSS, or JavaScript files do. They're all plain text formats.

Comment: Would the only option then be to change the file format to pdf or something like that?

Comment: If it's really a CSV file, no.

Comment: What do you use csv for?. Why do you need to change the font, please explain

Comment: @JorgeLondoño I try to output text with adresses as shipping labels. The labels are big and only 3 per A4 page. So i try to style that only 3 shipping adresses fits per A4 page (with space and font size). Then i can easy print >100 adresses.

Comment: @StefanTrailovic, CSV is a poor format for that type of thing. It's really a data format; it doesn't carry any information about how it should be displayed or printed. Generally, something like PDF is much better if you're trying to print in a particular format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do formatting with CSV (font-size, color, etc ...). If you want to do the formatting you can use this biletec to generate XLS https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Regards